# Herkunft und Etymologie von "na also"

Tags: phrase, particle, etymology

Die Kombination "na also" kann mehrere Bedeutungen haben.

> 1. *Na also!*  - Etwas überfälliges ist endlich eingetreten.
> 2. *Na also hören sie mal!* - Vorwurfsvolle Anrede.
> 3. *Na also ich weiß nicht.* - Füllwort zur Relativierung / zum "Zeit schinden".

In den Beispielen 2 und 3 übernehmen *na* und *also* lediglich die Rolle von Partikeln zur Betonung oder als Füllwörter. Im ersten Beispiel jedoch bilden zwei Partikeln zusammen einen vollständigen Satz mit feststehender Bedeutung. Ich frage mich, woher das kommt und ob es vielleicht eine etymologische Herleitung gibt.

Der Duden kennt *also* sowohl als  [Partikel](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/also_verstaerkende_Partikel)  als auch als  [Adverb](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/also_Adverb) , wobei ich bei letzterem vor allem die dritte Bedeutung "in ebendieser Weise" interessant finde. Hat das möglicherweise etwas mit diesem seltsamen Zwei-Partikeln-Satz "Na also!" zu tun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Also" war früher gebräuchlich, um ein einfaches "so" nachhaltig zu verstärken.(<sup>[1](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GA02921#XGA02921)</sup>) Die Bedeutung von "Na also!" kann man sich heutzutage deswegen besser vorstellen, wenn man es sich als "Na (genau) so!" vorstellt. Es handelt sich also (!) um eine Bestätigung zum vorher bereits Behaupteten.